# Read data from channel and print it at interval

Tags: go, channel

Let's say we have (delete) goroutine, that delete some files and send the deleted files count (counter) to (main) through a channel.
**example**:

```
func main() {
    filesList := []string{"file1", "file2", "file3", "file4"}
    channelStream := make(chan int)

    go func(files []string, channel chan<- int) {
        defer close(channel)

        counter := 0
        for _, file := range files {
            err := os.Remove(file)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            counter += 1
            channel <- counter
        }
    }(filesList, channelStream)

    for msg := range channelStream { //Read from channel until it is closed

        fmt.Printf("\r--> " + strconv.Itoa(msg) + " files removed")
    }
}
```

now, every time a file deleted, (counter) will be sent to the (main) and there it will be printed to the terminal, that is a lot of printing.
**My question is**: How to print (counter) at interval (let's say every 1 second)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common option is to buffer the output and flush it at regular intervals, which will allow for all different types of output to be accumulated:

```
out := bufio.NewWriter(os.Stdout)
defer out.Flush()

tick := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
defer tick.Stop()

for {
    select {
    case msg, ok := <-channelStream:
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(out, "--> %d files removed\n", msg)
        
    case <-tick.C:
        out.Flush()
    }
}
```

However since you only seem to be tracking and updating a counter value here, I would just update the counter itself and write it out at each interval:

```
tick := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
defer tick.Stop()

var counter int
var ok bool
for {
    select {
    case msg, ok := <-channelStream:
        if !ok {
            fmt.Printf("\r--> %d files removed", counter)
            return
        }
        counter += msg
    case <-tick.C:
        fmt.Printf("\r--> %d files removed", counter)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that answers my question... there is one thing, 

if !ok {
            fmt.Printf("\r--> %d files removed", counter)
            return
        }

in this code, (ok) is false, that happens when channel is closed, at this point the counter = 0 (you always get 0 when read from closed channel), simple solution is to use another variable to save (counter) value, read that variable when the channel is closed.

Comment: @Vamp808: good catch, I'll update the example.